# calling mounted after all properties are loaded in created

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

in my Vue App, I am fetching some data from remote API and then using that data to create a Html table. I have decided to go with the following flow.

fetch data from API in `created()` hook and set data properties there & then in `mounted()` hook call the method that is responsible for filling up my Html table.

but what happens is if my call to the api is asyc so as soon as created() is exited `mounted()` is called and since i dont have my data ready yet, i get errors. how can i defer this table population until the data fetching is complete.

here is some pseudo code for the flow;

```
created(){

  ayncJSON() {
    self.data = data;
  }
}

mounted(){
  self.populateTable();
}

populateTable(){

//use self.data to create table
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use promises....

Make an async call to fetch the data and then (it's literally 'then') do your populate function.

So it would look something like this...

```js
mounted () {
  $http.get('url_here').then( (response) => {
  self.data = response.data
  populateTable()
}) 
}
```

Hope that helps. If you use Vue Resource (as shown above) this includes $http.get which returns the promise for you. Check out the documentation.

Comment: should i always perform fetching of data & working with dom in `mounted()` hook?

Comment: Not necesarilly, depends when you want to fetch the data. It works for me though in general